# Error building iOS Framework: usr/local/bin/carthage: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

I have this error when building my project that include several external Frameworks that I have installed using Carthage :

> /Users/moneycup/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoneyCup-fawvvvubqmiqrzajrxdwjxeiaxbw/Build/Intermediates/MoneyCup.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoneyCup.build/Script-03D74C381DE83AC900F61FEE.sh: line 2: usr/local/bin/carthage: No such file or directory

I have absolutely no clue to what to do now.
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't know what is causing this problem or how to fix it, but I'd start by Googling for the error message, `usr/local/bin/carthage: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 24):

You have a build script in your project:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

(Find it in `Build Phases`), but Carthage can not be found.

[image]

To fix this:

- Make sure the script has a leading slash (`/usr/...` not `usr/`)

If this is not the issue:

- [install Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) 
  or remove the build script.

Comment: Thks. It works to remove the script ! Just for my understanding, what is the purpose of the script ?

Comment: The script works around [an Aplle bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216). I recommend to use the script but to (re-)install Carthage.

Comment: Yes, installing Carthage resolved the issue for me. The script already had the leading slash.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

Open Terminal to be sure Carthage's location. Write to Terminal:

```
open /opt/homebrew/bin
```

If Carthage is there, great.

Then,

Open your project

**Target -> Build Phases -> Run Script - Copy Carthage Dependencies**

Location Path should be:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

Then,

Build your project :)